# Avoiding Unpacking Patterns in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

In my SQLAlchemy wrapper, I tend to have redundant chunks of code that involve  repetitive logic as to whether to unpack the code.

For example

```
  def seek_entry(self, filter, model, multiple=False, unpack=False):
    if multiple:
      if unpack:
        return self.session.query(model).filter_by(**filter).all()
      else:
        return self.session.query(model).filter_by(filter).all()
    else:
      if unpack:
        return self.session.query(model).filter_by(**filter).first()
      else:
        return self.session.query(model).filter_by(filter).first()
```

Is there a way to not have to check `unpack` and `multiple` and to instead make this code more concise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could utilize [`filter()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.filter) method if the given `filter` isn't dictionary. See [source code](https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/2bc8c92279a165563b7ebcf82c96cd3cd7ede2a2/lib/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py#L1274-L1334) to see how `filter_by()` is calling `filter()` method.